# SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 Redistribution Agreement

Tags: sql-server-ce

I'm trying to sign up to redistribute SQL Server Compact Edition 3.5 but I cannot seem to find the page to register for redistribution.  I found this link http://www.microsoft.com/sql/editions/compact/redistribute.mspx that someone posted but that just directs me to the [homepage](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx).  If I go to the [4.0 download page](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876) there is a link for the [SQL Server Compact redistribution site](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=94589), but this just goes back to the same [homepage](http://www.microsoft.com/sqlserver/en/us/editions/compact.aspx).  I had to use the 4.0 page because I cannot seem to find the 3.5 page and any links like this one : [www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx](http://www.microsoft.com/Sqlserver/2005/en/us/compact.aspx) just go back to that same homepage.

Does anyone have a working link to where I can register?  Do I even have to register?  I found the SQL Server Compact 2005 Datasheet and in it says:

> SQL Server Compact Edition is free to
>   download, develop, and deploy
>   applications. SQL Server Compact
>   Edition is also free for third parties
>   to redistribute.

With a footnote that says:

> A simple redistribution agreement must
>   be signed online.

But if I go to the [4.0 download page](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876) it says:

> SQL Server Compact 4.0 is freely
>   redistributable under a redistribution
>   license agreement and application
>   developers redistributing SQL Server
>   Compact 4.0 can optionally register at
>   the SQL Server Compact redistribution
>   site. Registering will help the
>   developers in getting information
>   about SQL Server Compact critical
>   security patches and hot fixes that
>   can be further applied to the client
>   installations.

Did the terms change between 3.5 and 4.0? Every site I find implies you need to register to redistribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the terms changed... But they are the same now, if you look at the download pages: http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=5783 and http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=17876